# How to have both width constraint and equal width constraint

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, nslayoutconstraint

I have a parent view in xib and in that there are 3 buttons as its subviews they are equal in width, so assigned an equal width constraint(priority is 1000) to all 3, now all 3 buttons are taking equal width. This is working fine. Now there are some scenarios where there will be only 2 buttons needed, so I want to have only 2 buttons taking the whole space and no third button.

To achieve that i added a width constraint to all 3 button and set its priority to 999. Then made an IBoutlet and tried to put the constraint to zero. But it does not seems to work.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *fConstraint;
```

then checking the condition

```
if(item.isShareable == NO){
    self.fConstraint.constant = 0;
}
```

The constraint is not becoming zero.

I am missing something? How can I achieve it?

Hope you understand the question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be using a `UIStackView` for this

Comment: @FOOO Try with hiding the button which you don't want to show... if you are hiding the button its height constraint can cell to zero

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin can u tell how to use it. i am new to UIStackView

Comment: @FOOO doesn't matter if you are new to it, follow the same process as everything else and do some research. Go to google, type in the class name and hit search. You will see class references and tutorials

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin i added a UIstackview and all the subviews in it. then added equal constraints to the buttons. when one button is set to hidden all the buttons get hidden.

Comment: @FOOO you don't need any constraints, set the distribution to "Fill Equally"

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin the problem is that i have a 2 views between this button with width 1 so that it looks like a separator. Fill equally seems to stretch that separator view.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps to achieve what you required,

1. Set the leading/trailing constraints to the superView.
2. Set equal width constraints for all three buttons and set its priority to high.
3. Set 0 width constraints for all three buttons with priority required, but leave them deactivated in IB. And connect them to IBOutlets in code just as connecting views.
4. Activate any of the 0 width constraints to collapse the button you want, and later deactivate them to expand.

Note that just with 1 and 2 in place, you can achieve the equal-width view layout. And with 3 and 4, you can collapse/expand any of the views selectively.

Hope that helps you.

**Update**

I have created a demo for the purpose of demonstration of how to achieve the required result without using StackViews if you want to support iOS versions below 9, and here is the result below,

[image]

Comment: ... or you could use a `UIStackView` and set the one you don't want to hidden

Comment: @Bharat this makes all button width to become zero. I am setting priority for equal width and width same.

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin StackView is always better option than playing with constraints but UIStackViews support iOS version 9 and above.

Comment: @BharatModi the question is tagged as iOS9

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin, thanks for correcting me, still i would like to make readers aware of that, if someone is new and don't know that.

Comment: @BharatModi Can you please add the actual code. Or some programmatic steps

Answer (score 0):

You can try by taking outlet of equal width constraint,

Your scenario should be like,

Set `leading,trailing,top,fixed height and equal width` to every button in your view.

So, your first button should have two equal width constrains one with respect to second and one with respect to third.

so take outlate of any equal width constraint and change it's constant when required.

And i think you need to manage leading and trailing constraint's constant also to change position when hide one button.

Answer (score 0):

If the design of the buttons will change constantly, the better idea is building for code, using `percentage` logic.

Function:

```
- (float)percentage:(float)value withFatherView:(UIView *)fatherView isHeightPercentage:(BOOL)isHeightPercentage
{
    float viewValue = fatherView.frame.size.width;

    if (isHeightPercentage)
        viewValue = fatherView.frame.size.height;

    return (viewValue * value) / 100;
}
```